# AutoComplete TextBox Addresses

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, telerik

I am looking for something similar to the way an Apple iOS works when typing into text fields. My purpose will be for addresses.

Ex: 123 Blueberry Avenue

For instance if they start typing in '123' it won't do anything but 
as soon as they type in B it will popup with all B recommendations from a dictionary ('Blue', 'Bobcat', 'Batman', etc.,) and filter down. Once they complete a word and press space it'll repeat the process.

I have telerik which has a single search and autocomplete criteria, but I'm looking for something with a little more versatility. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik AutoCompleteBox is just what you need, what do you mean versatility?

Comment: Well from my understanding is Telerik's AutoCompleteBox only suggests whole phrases. So I provide a dictionary of the whole address names and it'll recommend the WHOLE address, but what I'm looking for is where it'll recommend word by word. one I finish typing 123 Blueberry it'll recommend all the street suffix options, such as Street, Avenue, Road, Boulevard, etc.,